# How can I make my computer detect my integrated camera?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, camera, integrated-camera

Not even the default windows 10 camera app can detect my laptop camera. I've looked online and they suggested checking device manager, but my camera didn't show up there either. Here's my computer hardware:
[My computer specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZndj.png). I have an msi laptop, but unfortunately, I don't know what the model number is because it isn't written anywhere on the laptop.

Comment: How do you know it's working? Have you tried another OS which detects it? Try a Linux Live boot disc. I find Ubuntu recognises most hardware. For a Windows user I would suggest [Ubuntu Mate](http://ubuntu-mate.org/).

Comment: It might help us if you provided specifications for your hardware.